# BOOTSTRAP CDN Hosted, additional CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, cdn

I'm using BOOTSTRAP via the CDN hosted by MAXcdn. But now I want to change something in the CSS files, but it's not on my server.

So my question is, how to deal with additional CSS when you are embedding your files via a CDN solution?

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you can overcome it by custom css, which  you need to create.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a new file called `custom.css` and include it inside `<head></head>` after the CDN versions.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Your Custom theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="your/path/to/custom/css/file">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Manoj Kumar, I realize that this is a solution. But is this really the way I should deal with it? Do you have experience in Bootstrap development, or is it your personal opinion?

Comment: This is the standard solution Krooy_Mans :)

Comment: @krooy_mans: What Manoj explained is the standard way to deal with bootstrap framework. typically framework includes a standard CSS code which we need to overwrite as per our need, and for that we generally use to overwrite it using `custom.css`

Comment: Ok great! Thanks for the additional comments and I'll take over you recommendations. Hopefully they will lead me to success ;)

Comment: @Manoj Kumar: I use this css order, but for example the bootstrap color of `navbar-brand` overrides my custom color for `navbar-brand` also if my css custom file is after the bootstrap cdn.

Comment: @Sefran2 Can you give the link to the site please?

Comment: @ManojKumar: now I'm working locally, I "resolved" by using !important. If necessary I'll use bootstrap locally after compiling with Less. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The best possible solution is overwriting CSS rules from bootstrap.css file into custom.css file.

for eg

If you include your `css (custom.css)` after Bootstrap's `(bootstrap.css),` you can override rules by redefining them.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Your Custom CSS code should go in this file-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
```

tip: make sure to add your custom.css file after bootstrap CDN file into your HTML document.